# MySQL use select for LEFT JOIN ON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

Just want to know can I make a such query?

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = (SELECT id FROM t3 WHERE t1.address LIKE 'street%' ORDER BY name ASC)
ORDER BY name DESC
```

This is because I want to add more complex query to the `LEFT JOIN` with sorting and order and some statements which depends on another table..
Thanks!

U.P.D.

```
SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE t1.address LIKE CONCAT(address,'%') ORDER BY LENGTH(address) DESC
```

Actually, I want to write this query as `LEFT JOIN` subquery (`ORDER BY` in case of `LIKE` does make sense!).

Comment: JOIN the subquery instead. (It may only return 1 row as it is now.)

Comment: @jarlh Ok, how to apply `ORDER BY` filter to the `LEFT JOIN` subquery?

Comment: "I make a such query?" - By the time you wrote this question you could just try to run the query.

Comment: That sub-query ORDER BY makes no sense anyway, just remove it.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Just want to know the best way to do this

Comment: You will need to explain what you want to do. From your query it's not clear because it doesn't make sense (though it might run).

Comment: @jarlh In case of `LIKE` operator `ORDER BY` does make huge sense :)

Comment: No, you can't do that. The subquery would return more than one result. Anyways, the subquery doesn't work  either

Comment: Your quesy is not clear  ...  try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: @nacho Thanks! I'll try to write in some other way..

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, @scaisEdge Sorry, I've updated my question. I want to apply `LIKE` and `ORDER BY` operators to the `LEFT JOIN` subquery somehow..

Comment: @mr.boris, is that supposed to be a joke?

Comment: @jarlh, seems not, you just don't understand the question, **nacho** already answered to my question

Comment: I understand what is clearly expressed.

Comment: Is this about optimisation/performance?

Comment: You are not clear. Eg explain what "such a query" means. You give an example but we must guess & it is not obvious. Use enough sentences to say what you mean. What does "U.P.D." mean? What does the stuff you added have to do with the preceding text? We can't read your mind. Please when you edit a post don't append edits, integrate changes to make the best presentation you can at that time. PS Tables have no order, result sets [sic] have order. Order by in a subquery without limit/top has no effect.

Comment: @P.Salmon optimisation/performance yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Theoretically* you can do this.

Writing subquery in join statement will have no effect other than filtering the cartesian product of the two tables just like the where condition. But writing query this way makes no sense as we don't know the context in which you are using it.

The above query can be written in much cleaner way as follows :

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t2.id in (SELECT id FROM t3 WHERE address LIKE 'street%') 
ORDER BY name DESC
```

It will produce the same result set as the query you provided